# Ideal super pom for a corporate use with Centralized Maven Plugin Management and Dependency Management in one shot

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-dependency

With the help of this post, I am trying to collate the best practices to Centralize the Maven Plugins and Dependencies in one pom ? Although few of the questions are bit obivious, I am still posting it as an open question for the sake of curating all the questions to conclude an ideal super pom for a corporate use. I welcome hearing from the Maven gurus.

1. Will `<pluginManagement>` from parent pom be inherited into child pom ?
2. Will `<dependencyManagement>` from parent pom be inherited into child pom ?
3. Will `<properties>` from parent pom be inherited into child pom ?
4. Will BOM pom import bring in dependencies from its `<dependencyManagement>` section ?
5. Will BOM pom import bring in plugins from its `<pluginManagement>` section ?
6. Will BOM pom import bring in properties from its `<properties>` section ?

Comment: Just one tip: top level poms that specify too much end up being annoying, as usually individual apps then need to go around overriding a lot of dependencies that otherwise would come in a transitive way. Only specify truly global dependencies and configuration. Also it might be unreal to re-release all apps after you do a change in the top level pom, so be aware that apps could be using 1+ year old top level poms. So bear in mind not all apps will be aligned to the latest version of your top level pom.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 to 4, the answer is yes.

For 5 and 6, I am not sure, but I guess the answer is no.